# Using read -p in a bash script that was executed from pipe

Tags: bash, pipe, wget, stdin

I apologize in advance - I don't fully understand the ideas behind what I'm asking well enough to understand why it's not working (**I don't know what I need to learn**). I searched stack exchange for answers first - I found some information that seemed possibly relevant, but didn't explain the concepts well enough that I understood how to build a working solution. I've been scouring google but haven't found any information that describes exactly what's going on in such a way that I understand. Any direction to background concepts that may help me understand what's going on would be greatly appreciated.

**Is it possible to get user input in a bash script that was executed from a pipe?**

For example:

```
wget -q -O - http://myscript.sh | bash
```

And in the script:

```
read -p "Do some action (y/n): " __response
if [[ "$__response" =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then
   echo "Performing some action ..."
fi
```

As I understand it, this doesn't work because read attempts to read the input from stdin  and the bash script is currently "executing through that pipe" (i'm sure there is a more technical accurate way to describe what is occurring, but i don't know how).

I found a solution that recommended using:

```
read -t 1 __response </dev/tty
```

However, this does not work either.

Any light shed on the concepts I need to understand to make this work, or explanations of why it is not working or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `tty` solution works.  Test it with this code, for example:

```
$ date | { read -p "Echo date? " r </dev/tty ; [ "$r" = "y" ] && cat || echo OK ; }
Echo date? y
Sat Apr 12 10:51:16 PDT 2014
$ date | { read -p "Echo date? " r </dev/tty ; [ "$r" = "y" ] && cat || echo OK ; }
Echo date? n
OK
```

The prompt from `read` appears on the terminal and `read` waits for a response before deciding to echo the date or not.

What I wrote above differs from the line below in two key aspects:

```
read -t 1 __response </dev/tty
```

First, the option `-t 1` gives `read` a timeout of one second.  Secondly, this command does not provide a prompt.  The combination of these two probably means that, even though `read` was *briefly* asking for input, you didn't know it.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason why this is not working is, as the OP validly indicated,

- The `|` <pipe> which is used, sends the standard output from the first command as standard input to the second command. In this case, the first command is

  ```
  wget -q -O - http://myscript.sh
  ```

  which passes a downloaded script via the pipe to its interpreter `bash`
- The `read` statement in the script uses *the same* standard input to obtain its value.

So this is where it collapses because `read` is not awaiting input from you but takes it from its own script. Example:

```
$ cat - <<EOF | bash 
> set -x
> read p
> somecommand
> echo \$p
> EOF
+ read p
+ echo somecommand
somecommand
```

In this example, I used a here-document which is piped to bash. The script enables debugging using `set -x` to show what is happening. As you see, `somecommand` is never executed but actually read by `read` and stored in the variable `p` which is then outputted by `echo` (note, the `$` has been escaped to avoid the substitution in the here-document).

**So how can we get this to work then?**

First of, never pipe to an interpreter such as `{ba,k,z,c,tc,}sh`. It is ugly and should be avoided, even though it feels the natural thing to do. The better thing to do is to use any of its options:

> **`bash -c string`:** If the `-c` option is present, then commands are read from string.  If there are arguments after the string, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with `$0`.

```
$ bash -c "$(command you want to pipe)"
```

This also works for `zsh`, `csh`, `tcsh`, `ksh`, `sh` and probably a lot of others.