# Why read -p won't work when use curl to get bash script?

Tags: bash, curl

I use `curl https://carry0987.github.io/repo/ | sudo bash`
to run the script with `read -p`, but it didn't work at all

It won't wait for user to type the value..

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

echo '1) Install Main Pkg'
echo '2) Tools'
echo '3) Rclone Mount'
echo '4) Delete Rclone Mount'
read -p 'Which tool do you want to use ? ' tool

link1=https://raw.github.com/carry0987/Raspberry-Pi-Repo/master/Setup/Install-Main-Pkg.sh
link2=https://raw.github.com/carry0987/Raspberry-Pi-Repo/master/Tools/tools.sh
link3=https://raw.github.com/carry0987/Raspberry-Pi-Repo/master/Rclone-Mount/rclone-mount.sh
link4=https://raw.github.com/carry0987/Raspberry-Pi-Repo/master/Rclone-Mount/delete-rclone-mount.sh

#Detect tools
case $tool in
  1)
    wget $link1 -O `basename $link1`
    ;;
  2)
    wget $link2 -O `basename $link2`
    ;;
  3)
    wget $link3 -O `basename $link3`
    ;;
  4)
    wget $link4 -O `basename $link4`
    ;;
  *)
    echo 'Tools not supported'
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

And if I use `curl https://carry0987.github.io/repo/ | sudo bash` to run it, it give me this:
[image]

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033880/using-read-p-in-a-bash-script-that-was-executed-from-pipe

Comment: @lojza Sorry for my mistake, I have add `</dev/tty` inthe end and it works now !      Thanks a lot !!

Comment: The question is, do you understand why this is the case? The `|` <pipe> which you use, sends the standard output from the first command as standard input to the second command. The `read` which you use, uses the standard input to obtain its value. So this is where it is failing.

Actually, the value of the variable `tool` obtains is the value of the empty-line between the `read`-statement and the variable declaration `link1`. You can see this if you replace that empty line with two lines containing both `echo $tool`. The best answer would be to call it as: `bash -c "$(curl bla)"`

Comment: @kvantour Thanks you very much !!! Now I know how pipe do and I fix this script with your explanation, great answer !

Comment: @kvantour One more question, if you use curl to run script, you recommend use `bash -c "$(curl https://example.com/repo/)"` or write down `</dev/tty` in the script?

Comment: I would suggest using the former option (`bash -c "$(curl foobar)"`). While the usage of `< /dev/tty` sounds appealing, it actually adds complexity to the stand-alone script and is a _dirty_ fix to make it work in this particular case using the pipe. In general, there are no good reasons to use `/dev/tty` at all and it should only be used if you can't find a simple solution to the problem. It is understandable that the usage of the `|` <pipe> feels more natural, but in this case, I would say _never pipe to bash_.

Comment: Also, you should always work with the concept _[keep it simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overengineering)_. Using nifty tools, tricks which you hardly every use make maintainablilty very hard and also often lead to the rediscovered [Aha-erlebnis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eureka_effect) when you or somebody else revisits your code fragment several months later and say: _"what is this ...,"_ while several precious moments later you go: _"Aha ... that is why"_. This process is then repeated over and over again until you document the code. (Sorry for going on a tangent)

Comment: @carry0987 I have answered your question [in the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033880/using-read-p-in-a-bash-script-that-was-executed-from-pipe). There is some more information there.

Comment: @kvantour I have learned it : **Keep It Simple**.                                                 I will update my README.md in github, thanks for your answer !